# Bootstrap thumbnail list is not showing thumbnails

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails, image

I am using twitter bootstrap on a theme I downloaded, and my custom html in my bootstrap thumbnails list is showing but the images are not.

Investigating the code, shows the image tag and working image locations are there. Here is a picture of what is occurring:

[image]

The code for my thumbnail list is this:

```
<div class="span9 space"><ul class="thumbnails"><li class="span3">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img data-src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/brewerydbapi/beer/YAKFea/upload_1CxY2l-medium.png" alt="">
                            <h3>90 Shilling</h3>
                            <p>Odell Brewing Company</p>
                        </div>
                    </li><li class="span3">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img data-src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/brewerydbapi/beer/oeGSxs/upload_FiPLQC-medium.png" alt="">
                            <h3>Naughty 90</h3>
                            <p>Toppling Goliath Brewing Company</p>
                        </div>
                    </li><li class="span3">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img data-src="noImage.gif" alt="">
                            <h3>90-Shilling Scotch Ale</h3>
                            <p>Taps Fish House & Brewery</p>
                        </div>
                    </li><li class="span3">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img data-src="noImage.gif" alt="">
                            <h3>Williams Ceilidh 90</h3>
                            <p>Williams Brothers Brewing Company</p>
                        </div>
                    </li><li class="span3">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img data-src="noImage.gif" alt="">
                            <h3>Boscos 90 Shilling Ale</h3>
                            <p>Boscos Brewing Company</p>
                        </div>
                    </li><li class="span3">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img data-src="noImage.gif" alt="">
                            <h3>Dundee Export 90 Scotch Ale</h3>
                            <p>Dundee Brewing Co.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li><li class="span3">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img data-src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/brewerydbapi/beer/qqTzHb/upload_mGIvsJ-medium.png" alt="">
                            <h3>90 Minute IPA</h3>
                            <p>Dogfish Head Craft Brewery</p>
                        </div>
                    </li><li class="span3">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img data-src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/brewerydbapi/beer/jdQySZ/upload_jbcADO-medium.png" alt="">
                            <h3>I-90 India Pale Ale</h3>
                            <p>Ancient Lakes Brewing Company</p>
                        </div>
                    </li></ul>                    

            </div>
```

Lastly there are zero errors showing in the chrome inspect element, and I dont have any inline css on this page.

Comment: Instead of data-src on your image tag try just src.

Comment: Here's a ground-zero fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BZudQ/ Using 'src' does work, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: Updated fiddle showing a working image: http://jsfiddle.net/BZudQ/1/

Comment: Thanks guys that worked... not sure why either.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`data-src` is used to get a place holder image in the bootstrap examples.  Just use `src`

Comment: Please check well before you approve too minor edits :)

Comment: Why `<img class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/sr/0/0c/Firefox-logo.png" alt="" />` works but not local images like `<img class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" src="http://localhost/live/images/logo.png" alt="" />`? Image is visible anywhere else!