# How to load bootstrap thumbnail images

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, image

I've started using Bootstrap for a project, and in particular, the Thumbnails component. On the [thumbnails example on the documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#thumbnails), the following sample code is shown:

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
  <li class="span4">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="">
    </a>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Notice the use of `data-src` to replace the usual `src` attribute on the `<img>` tag.

I assumed that to get my thumbnails working, I should use `data-src` instead of `src` for the images, but that does not seem to be the case. I've only been able to load images by defining the `src` attribute. It seems [others are having the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862758/bootstrap-thumbnail-list-is-not-showing-thumbnails).

Is this a typo in the documentation, or did I not understand correctly how to use `data-src`?

Comment: I dug a little and I found that from bootstrap 2.2.2 holder.js has been replaced by placehold.it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap thumbnail list is not showing thumbnails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862758/bootstrap-thumbnail-list-is-not-showing-thumbnails)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I believe that the only reason of why bootstrap guys are using `data-src` instead `src`, it's because of `holder.js`. You should use `src` instead of `data-src` because `data-src` is only used for the javascript library that generates the example images of a certain size, and `src` is the normal attribute for specifying the location of an image (Source: [W3C](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/img#HTML_Attributes))

**Why are they using in the documentation `data-src`?** I suppose that even the syntax `<img src="holder.js/100x200"></img>` is accepted by the library as it is in the [holder.js documentation](http://imsky.github.com/holder/), when we access to the page it throws a 404 error in the image even when the image is displaying, because there is not any file in the specified path, what it's weird.

**Why do they put that in the documentation code?** I really don't know. Probably it's a mistake. But I am sure that you should use `src` instead `data-src` in thumbnails.

Comment: It works also with `data-src` in `bootstrap 3`. The crucial thing is to download the library and add it to our project. https://github.com/imsky/holder

Answer (score 23):

### How to use it

Include `holder.js` in your HTML:

```
<script src="holder.js"></script>
```

Holder will then process all images with a specific `src` attribute, like this one:

```
<img src="holder.js/200x300">
```

The above tag will render as a placeholder 200 pixels wide and 300 pixels tall.

To avoid console 404 errors, you can use `data-src` instead of `src`.

Holder also includes support for themes, to help placeholders blend in with your layout. There are 6 default themes: `sky`, `vine`, `lava`, `gray`, `industrial`, and `social`. You can use them like this:

```
<img src="holder.js/200x300/industrial">
```

Comment: So you have to include holder.js separately than what's included in Bootstrap and that's not explained in the documentation?

Comment: Yes, holder is a separate framework you would be responsible for loading in.  https://github.com/imsky/holder

Answer (score 5):

Bootstrap uses Holder for thumbnails in its documentation.

It's pretty well explained on [the Holder github page](https://github.com/imsky/holder).

> Include holder.js in your HTML. Holder will then process all images with a specific src attribute... The tag will render as a placeholder. To avoid console 404 errors, you can use data-src instead of src.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't figure it out either, as far as I understand it holder.js is actually a completely separate js file to act as an img placeholder from http://imsky.github.io/holder/

data-src is used to pass to the javascript, the /100x200 is the dimension of the picture you want the javascript 'holder.js' to take up for the real img.

I think the idea is to prototype using this (data-src="holder.js/300x200") and then replace it with sized pictures (src="Logo.png") afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

In order for me to get this to work, I had to call the run() function in holder.

I am using require to load backbone views, inside my view I include holder

```
var Holder = require('holderjs');
```

Then inside render I can run

```
Holder.run();
```

And in my template  I have

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img data-src="holder.js/200x200/text:hello world">
  <div class="caption">
    <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
    <p>...</p>
    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

For future Googlers looking for how to use with NPM/build jobs this worked in my case:

```
window.Holder = require('holderjs').default;
```