# How do I get holder.js to work with bootstrap 4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-4, holder.js, bootstrap-4

Their example is this:

```
<img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100%x180/" alt="Card image cap">
```

So I thought if I included:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/holder/2.9.0/holder.js"></script>
```

It would work, but it doesn't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load bootstrap thumbnail images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15645161/how-to-load-bootstrap-thumbnail-images)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example is outdated. [Percentage widths should be specified with a p, not a % sign](https://github.com/imsky/holder#fluid-placeholders):

```
<img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px180/" alt="Card image cap">
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/8p3absau/

Comment: Are you kidding me? How can the example on bootstrap4 alpha be outdated? Oh well. Thanks imsky!